# MYSQL - SQL como comprar el idPedido(PrimaryKey) de mi tabla pedidos vs el idPedido de mi tabla detallePedido(Foreign Key)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

Lo que quiero es poder imprimir los productos registrados por clientes

Esta es la tabla de pedidos, solo hay 2 registros

[image: Esta es la tabla de pedidos, solo hay 2 registros]

Esta es la tabla de los detalles de los pedidos registrados hay 3, 2 pertenecen a jostick y 1 a omar

[image: Esta es la tabla de los detalles de los pedidos registrados hay 3, 2 pertenecen a jostick y 1 a omar]

Mi problema es que cuando hago la consulta, me trae los registros que no corresponden, yo quiero poder traer mediante el `idPedido` los productos registrados por el mismo cliente... donde el `pedidos.idPedido = detallepedidos.idPedido` sean iguales

**AQUI DEJO EL CODIGO DE LA CONSULTA**

```
SELECT p.idPedido, d.idPedido, d.idDetalle, p.nombre, p.monto,
d.codproducto, d.montolinea, p.monto FROM detallepedidos d , pedidos p
WHERE d.idPedido = 1
```

[image: Mi problema es que cuando hago la consulta, me trae los registros que no corresponden, yo quiero poder traer mediante el idPedido los productos registrados por el mismo cliente... donde el pedidos.idPedido = detallepedidos.idPedido sean iguales **AQUI DEJO EL CODIGO DE LA CONSULTA** SELECT p.idPedido, d.idPedido, d.idDetalle, p.nombre, p.monto, d.codproducto, d.montolinea, p.monto FROM detallepedidos d , pedidos p WHERE d.idPedido = 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que realizar el enlace entre las dos tablas mediante el **idPedido**.

Lo que me parece raro es que tu mismo lo estás indicando en la pregunta donde dices [*... donde el pedidos.idPedido = detallepedidos.idPedido sean iguales ...*].

El código Sql sería así:

```
SELECT p.idPedido, d.idPedido, d.idDetalle, p.nombre, p.monto,
d.codproducto, d.montolinea, p.monto 
FROM detallepedidos d , pedidos p
WHERE p.idPedido = d.idPedido AND d.idPedido = 1
```

Comment: gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo, yo la realice de una manera parecida, pero probe tu consulta y tambien me funciona perfectamente

Comment: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.idPedido, d.idPedido, d.idDetalle, p.nombre, 
               p.monto, d.codproducto, d.montolinea, p.monto 
FROM pedidos p 
LEFT JOIN detallepedidos d ON p.idPedido = d.idPedido
```

PD: Te recomiendo que uses una nomenclatura snake case para los nombres de las columnas

Comment: si? soy nuevo en esto, pero investigare sobre ello, ya solucione lo de la consulta muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta consulta a ver si es lo que necesitas.
Retorna los datos correspondientes al cliente especificado (En este caso especificamos el `ID` de Jostick)

Agregué un inner join entre las dos tablas.

```
    SELECT p.idPedido, 
           d.idPedido, 
           d.idDetalle, 
           p.nombre, 
           p.monto, 
           d.codproducto, 
           d.montolinea, 
           p.monto 
FROM detallePedido d 
inner join pedido p on p.idPedido=d.idPedido and d.idPedido = 1;
```

Comment: gracias tambien me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias funciona, bueno yo revise la consulta y la hice de esta manera, es muy parecida SELECT p.idPedido, d.idPedido, d.idDetalle, p.nombre, p.monto,
d.codproducto, d.montolinea, p.monto 
FROM detallepedidos d , pedidos p
WHERE p.idPedido & d.idPedido =  1

Pero la tuya también funciona excelente gracias.